# C# WPF - Timer Stops on ControlBox Click

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, controlbox

I have a WPF Application using a `DispatcherTimer`. When the user MouseDowns on any button in the ControlBox ('-' Minimize, '□' Maximize, 'X' Exit), the `DispatcherTimer` stops - even if the buttons are disabled. If the user moves the mouse outside of the ControlBox area (nothing will be triggered on release), the `DispatcherTimer` will not resume until the mouse is released.

I need the ControlBox to be visible and enabled.

Is there any way to keep the `DispatcherTimer` running continuously until the WPF application is terminated?

To provide an example: In Google Chrome, navigating to any video / gif and then clicking in the ControlBox will immediately cause the video / gif to pause playback (you can try it on YouTube). However, this phenomena does not occur in Firefox. Thanks for any help!

Comment: did n't understand what you are trying to say? can u give one more example?

Comment: Have you tried increasing your DispatcherTimer priority ?

Comment: Ok, Just tested with higher priority and this is not working.  That's a very strange issue.  The tick events are never fired

Comment: I can show you my code but it's super basic. I think the entire process stops, not just the Timer. Basically, as soon as you click the ControlBox, everything is paused. I don't know how to add linebreaks in comments. Sorry for the formatting. `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer blockTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(); blockTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimedEvent); blockTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); blockTimer.Start();`